# While deriving Least Squares Estimators, how to find the derivate of a summation operate?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, least-squares, derivative

I'm calculating the Least Squares Estimators. There was one step here:

$\frac{d}{d\hat\alpha}{\sum(y_i-\hat\alpha-\hat\beta x_i)}^2=0$ -->
$-2{\sum(y_i-\hat\alpha-\hat\beta x_i)}=0$

I know it is related to the chain rule, yet I don't know how it is applied here. Can someone please explain? Huge huge thanks!

Comment: derivative of (a+b) = derivative of a + derivative of b.

Comment: @seanv507 I'm not sure that's the most relevant derivative rule being used, here. The chain rule is the key.

Answer (score 2):

We have
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{d\hat\alpha}\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\hat\alpha-\hat\beta x_i)^2
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{d}{d\hat\alpha}(y_i-\hat\alpha-\hat\beta x_i)^2\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n2(y_i-\hat\alpha-\hat\beta x_i)\cdot\frac{d}{d\hat\alpha}(y_i-\hat\alpha-\hat\beta x_i)\quad\text{(chain rule)}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n2(y_i-\hat\alpha-\hat\beta x_i)\cdot(-1).
\end{align*}